# Sencha Touch: Calling a php function from Sencha Touch example results in invalid JSON string Error.

Tags: php, javascript, json, extjs

I am brand new to Sencha Touch.  I followed Sencha Touch's "Getting Started" example video (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started).  In the example there is a contact form(the code follows) that calls a php function that is left undefined in the video, resulting in a file not found console error.  When I add a php function I get the following console error:

**" Uncaught Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: "**

I get this error even if the file is empty.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Or any pointers to tutorials explaining how to call php functions from Sencha?

### The contact form code to see how the php function is called:

```
Ext.define('GS.view.Contact', {
    extend:  'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype:  'contactform',

    requires:  [
        'Ext.form.FieldSet',
        'Ext.field.Email'
        ],

    config:  {
        title:  'Contact',
        iconCls:  'user',
        **url:  'php/Contact.php',**

        items:  [
            {
                xtype:  'fieldset',
                title:  'Contact Us',
                instructions:  '(email is not required)',
                items:  [
                    {
                        xtype:  'textfield',
                        name:  'name',
                        label:  'Name'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:  'emailfield',
                        name:  'email',
                        label:  'Email'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype:  'textareafield',
                        name:  'message',
                        label:  'Message'
                    }
                ]

            },

            {
                xtype:  'button',
                text:  'Send',
                ui:  'confirm',
                **handler:  function(){
                    this.up('contactform').submit();**
                    }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is pretty self explanatory. The output of the PHP script you are calling is not properly formatted JSON. For instance, you need to put the correct JSON headers up on your HTTP response, you also need to make sure that the actual data is JSON.

Can you try replacing your PHP file with something like this to see if you could get past the error?

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo "{\"success\":true, \"message\":\"Hello World\"}";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you – that worked.  Self explanatory I am sure if you are coming from the client side world.  I am coming from a real time embedded C++ background(like SW to boot cell phone or guide a missile) w/ some experience in server side php and mySQL. Very light experience in javascript/DOM so this is a steep learning curve for me.  I just learned what JSON was last week.  On the server side you can invoke a php script simply to do some calculations and stuff data into SQL tables.  I was assuming it would be the same here.  Can you recommend any sites/books that would help me come up to speed?

Comment: I think coming from that background you'll be just fine :)

So you can still do all that you want in PHP, just that the interface between the server side and front end needs to be something restful in this case (there are other options, but REST is probably easiest to start with). 

Honestly there is plenty of content online.. here and on many blogs.

Answer (score 0):

The error says the received JSON is invalid. Make sure the PHP page creates valid JSON. You can start by simply outputting a hard-coded string that you know is valid JSON.

Also, make sure the page is sending the correct content type to the browser by using these headers:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header("content-type:application/json");
```